# Gypsum board damages(fire rated)

Tags: civil-engineering, construction-management

Is it acceptable for fire-rated gypsum board to be stored outdoor (covered parking area) in a humid city?
Is it acceptable to be damaged at edges and sides?
Does it need spacers when stored flat on each others?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Officially Gypsum panels should be stored inside where they are not exposed to inclement weather, the Gypsum Association states "Gypsum panel products shall not be stored in areas of excessive humidity", unfortunately they do not specify what constitutes excessive humidity. However, exposure of Gypsum to high moisture levels can lead to water stains, discolouration, mold, paper de lamination, and sag.

The damage shown in the picture looks severe enough that it would need to be repaired in order for the panels to maintain the required fire-rated separation between areas.

There is no need to put spacers in between the boards providing they are stacked on a flat surface on top of each other. There is a limit on the height of stacks which is 17 feet (5m).

Gypsum Association Handling Procedures: https://www.pabcogypsum.com/sites/default/files/GA-801-07.pdf

Gypsum Association - Repair of Fire-Rate Gypsum Panels: https://www.gypsum.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/GA-225-15.pdf